# Async task for batch http requests

Tags: android, android-asynctask, xmlhttprequest

I need to make a batch of HTTP requests and feed the responses to a `ListView` one by one. I am using an async task and running a `for` loop of requests in a `doBackgroundProcess` method. Is that a correct approach? If not, please guide me to the best practise.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *entirely* clear what you're trying to do. If you're doing the following:

1. Collect a set of HTTP requests
2. Send them.
3. Get back the results.
4. Post to an adapter backing a list view
5. Wait for the user to initiate the next set of HTTP requests

then I suggest you look into an IntentService. If your Activity goes into the background for any reason, AsyncTask will stop, but IntentService continues until it's done all its work.

I'd even suggest you stick your HTTP results in a content provider. It's best to persist data that takes a long time to retrieve. Your users will like you for it! You can also stop when you lose connectivity, and then re-start where you left off, if you have the data already. And if connectivity isn't available at the start, you can show users the most recent results.

Remember that the network isn't always available.